# Prove that $\boldsymbol{\ f}$ is a constant function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functional-equations

if :$$f:[0,1]→\mathbb{R}$$
and for all $x\in[0,1]$
 $$f(x)=f\!\left(x^2\right)$$
and for all $b\in[0,1]$
$$ \lim_{ x \to b }f(x)=f(b)$$

prove : for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$, for all $x\in[0,1]$, $f(x)=c$

Comment: What is the meaning of $c$?

Comment: Can you mention your solution and where you faced problem

Comment: I believe you are asking us to show that $f$ is a constant function.

Comment: @caverac constant number

Comment: @robjohn .yes ..

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** For any $x\in(0,1)$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2^n}=0
$$
Show that for $x\in(0,1)$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\,f\!\left(x^{2^n}\right)=f(0)
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\,f\!\left(x^{2^n}\right)=f(x)
$$
Show that
$$
\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=f(1)
$$

Comment: This is a hint. Try applying $f$ and looking at the things you are given.

Comment: Not that it makes a difference, but judging from OP's history, I think he won't be answering.

Answer (score 1):

Letting x be an arbitrary positive and less than 1, f(x)=f(x^2)=f(x^4)... The arguments converge to 0 so the function value must approach f(0). But this is then f(x) by continuity. But x was arbitrary so f is constant on [0,1). Similarly f(1)=f(x).

Comment: Is $\lim_{ x \to b }f(x)=f(b)$ from the original problem necessary to show f is constant? I thought simply $f(x)=f(x^2)\ \ \forall x \in [0,1]$ would be enough.

Comment: @MateenUlhag No that is not sufficient. That limit (continuity) is necessary. Note the endpoints of your interval square to themselves.

Comment: No. The behavior of the square-roots and squares of x is independent of the behavior of most other x's. Note the choice of f(x) cannot "get to" more than aleph null x values (without continuity).

Answer (score 0):

The function $x\to x^2$ is a bijection of $[0,1]$ and, for instance, $$\lim_{ x \to \frac 12}f(x)=f\left(\frac 12\right)\text{ and } \lim_{ x \to \frac 14 }f(x)=f\left(\frac 14\right)$$ then $$f\left(\frac 12\right)=f\left(\frac 14\right)$$ Hence for all $n$ $$f\left(\frac 12\right)=f\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$$ Similarly for all $n$$$f\left(\frac 1x\right)=f\left(\frac{1}{x^{2^n}}\right)$$